# Really hard time understanding this query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The following query is supposed to return "sailors who have reserved all boats"

and here's the mySQL code

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    ((SELECT B.bid  
     FROM Boats B)
    Except
    (SELECT R.bid  
     FROM Reserves R
     WHERE R.sid = S.sid))
```

And I just...don't know how to read through it. I understand that the subquery that follows "NOT EXISTS" should return the boat id (bid) for all the records on the Boats table. So the query that follows Except should be returning the boat ids for all the boats that have been reserved...so that means if there is someone who reserved all boats, nothing should return, meaning the NOT EXISTS will evaluate to true and it will just give the name of that sailor? I think it's the last part that confuses me...how does it end up returning the name of the sailor?

Comment: I'm not aware that MySQL supports an EXCEPT clause

Comment: @Strawberry that's interesting. My professor made us download MySQL server to practice doing SQL queries yet she gives us non MySQL examples (like this one). Sigh.

Comment: @shA.t This is the query my professor gave me. I'm more looking for like..an english translation of what it does than a correction for it..I believe  that the subquery returns all the boat ids that have NOT been reserved. So when I read "NOT EXISTS", what is the NOT EXISTS being applied to? What is it that doesn't exist? Is it saying "find the sname that doesn't exist in the table of all the boat ids that were not reserved?" And if that table doesn't itself have the snames (just the boat ids), how does it get ANY names returned at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some boats those can be reserved by sailors, Sailors are registered and we know them, So the structure of tables are:

```
[Table: Boats]          [Table: Sailors]        [Table: Reserves]
+-----+--------+        +-----+----------+      +-----+-----+-----+
| bid | bname  |        | sid | sname    |      | rid | bid | sid |
+-----+--------+        +-----+----------+      +-----+-----+-----+
| 1   | Boat 1 |        | 1   | Sailor 1 |      | 1   | 1   | 1   |
| 2   | Boat 2 |        | 2   | Sailor 2 |      | 2   | 2   | 3   |
| 3   | Boat 3 |        | 3   | Sailor 3 |      +-----+-----+-----+
+-----+--------+        +-----+----------+
```

In the above data when you need to know which boats are not reserved; you can use below query that will give you bid => 3:

```
SELECT B.bid  FROM Boats B
EXCEPT
SELECT R.bid  FROM Reserves R;
```

And when you need to know which boats are not (ever) reserved by a sailor; you can use below query that will give you bid => [1, 3] for sid = 3:

```
SELECT B.bid  FROM Boats B
EXCEPT
SELECT R.bid  FROM Reserves R  WHERE R.[sid] = 3;
```

And when a sailor reserves all boats the above query will have no result, So `NOT EXISTS(<above query>)` will be true. Now you can use above query to found sailors that reserves all boats like this:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT B.bid  FROM Boats B
    EXCEPT
    SELECT R.bid  FROM Reserves R
    WHERE R.[sid] = S.[sid]);
```

So If data of `Reserves` become something like this:

```
 [Table: Reserves]
 +-----+-----+-----+
 | rid | bid | sid |
 +-----+-----+-----+
 | 1   | 1   | 1   |
 | 2   | 2   | 1   |
 | 3   | 3   | 1   |
 +-----+-----+-----+
```

Your query will give a result of `Sailor 1` ;).

---

More info:
**`EXCEPT`** returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t output by the right input query.
**`EXISTS`**: Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

Comment: about to read through this, but at the end, when you define EXCEPT, shouldn't it say "return distinct rows from the left input query that  ARE outputted by the right input query"? @shA.t

Comment: @FrostyStraw [It comes from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Comment: okay so..is any of the following incorrect: is the NOT EXISTS applied one by one to every row in sailors? For example, for sid = 1, it will do the query inside NOT EXISTS, and if no rows are returned, it will just return the name of the sailor matching that id? Then it'll go to sid = 2 (assuming multiple sailors can reserve a boat at the same time), and if no rows are returned again, then the sailor name matching sid =2 will be returned, otherwise it will continue to sid =3, and so on and so forth? @shA.t

Comment: I can say yes; DBMS is doing it so close to it; you can check validation of inner-select of EXISTS by doing a test of manually setting values for outer values (like S.[sid]) ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the sql, the subselect

```
(SELECT B.bid  
 FROM Boats B)
Except
(SELECT R.bid  
 FROM Reserves R
 WHERE R.sid = S.sid)
```

should be the same as

```
(SELECT B.bid  
 FROM Boats B
 WHERE B.sid <> S.sid)
```

If you substitute the part in the main sql you get

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT B.bid  
 FROM Boats B
 WHERE B.sid <> S.sid)
```

Select only those Sailors for which no Boats with other `sid`'s exists, which is the same as "sailors who have reserved all boats"